# What's the wrong with my qsort in linux?

Tags: c, linux, qsort

I am using Mac OS to implement part of function of command sort:
part of my code is below:

```
int compare(const void *p, const void *q) {
    return strcmp(*(char **)p, *(char **)q);
}
void sort_file(char *filename, int unique, int reverse) {
    /* TODO: Complete this function */
    /* Note: you will probably need to implement some other functions */
    char buf[1024][1024];
    int i=0;
    FILE * fp;
    if(!(fp=fopen(filename,"r"))){
        perror("Open error!");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(fgets(buf[i],1024,fp)){
        printf("%s",buf[i]);
        i++;
    }
    qsort(buf, i, sizeof(char *), compare);
}
```

The result always show `segmentation fault: 11`
Anyone can tell me what's the problem and how to modify it?

I still  want to know, if I don't know the maximum size of code in one line and in the file, how to define my array?

I get the idea from this page:
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml

Comment: Your stride is completely wrong. `sizeof(char*)` should be `sizeof *buf` (which, btw, is a helluva lot larger than a `char*`). Think about that a minute, then consider how your comparator has to change as well.

Comment: at first, I write it as qsort(buf,i,1024,compare), but same problem

Comment: Anybody know why is the downvote? :<

Comment: Twas not I, but I conjecture it was probably because there was little evidence of debugging effort before coming here. Honestly, this was in better shape than most posts I see these days. At least a block of code, including your comparator, with little required modification was posted, and intent was clearly stated. A "this is what I tried to find the problem..." list and debugger output for where the segfault reports would probably have avoided the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have an array of pointers; you have an array of arrays. Each element in your array of arrays has a specific, fixed stride of 1024 `char`. `qsort` needs to know that, and you're not telling it. First change this:

```
qsort(buf, i, sizeof(char *), compare);
```

to this:

```
qsort(buf, i, sizeof *buf, compare);
```

Now `qsort` knows how big each "thing" is in your array of char arrays.

Next, your comparator should be altered to account for the address being passed and what it is as it pertains to your array of arrays. Each address passed to the comparator is where an element lays. But your elements are each `char[1024]`. The address of some `char[1024]` isn't some `char**`, it is `char(*)[1024]`. There are no pointers to pointers involved here. Your comparator can simply be:

```
int compare(const void *p, const void *q) 
{
    const char (*lhs)[1024] = p;
    const char (*rhs)[1024] = q;
    return strcmp(*lhs, *rhs);
}
```

Next, there is no limiter in you control loop to prevent overflowing your array of arrays. In short, this:

```
while(fgets(buf[i],1024,fp))
```

should be this:

```
while(i < 1024 && fgets(buf[i],1024,fp))
```

and ideally, that 1024 should be expressed as a constant somewhere to avoid magic number sprinkling.

Finally, you're leaking an open `FILE*` in your function. Not a good plan. Make sure to `fclose()` your file pointer.

Comment: @WeihengLi You want to be more specific than "that error" ? I just tested the above changes with your code on sorting of 1024 randomly selected entries from `/usr/share/dict/words` and it worked *perfectly*.

Comment: Do you know why the size of *buf is not 1024?

Comment: @WeihengLi Don't know what you're doing differently, but given `char buf[1024][1024]`, the value of `sizeof *buf` is indeed `1024`. [**See it live here**](http://ideone.com/sryX5n).

Comment: You're passing incorrect pointers to strcmp. The void pointers passed to the compare function are pointers to arrays. See Sahu's answer.

Comment: the types are indeed different, and I actually noted the correct types in my answer text. I'll change the proc because (a) you're correct, it should be accurate, and (b) RSahu's answer is accurate on method, but incorrect on actual type; they're as-described previously in my answer, `char(*)[1024]`, not `char(*)[1000]`. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2):

Problems I see:

**Wrong argument to `qsort`**

```
qsort(buf, i, sizeof(char *), compare);
```

Needs to be:

```
qsort(buf, i, sizeof(buf[0]), compare);
```

Since the difference between  `buf+1` and `buf` is 1000 `char`s, it is wrong to use `sizeof(char*)` as the third argument.

**Wrong casting of the arguments in `compare`**

The original pointers are of type `char (*)[1000]`, not `char**`. Hence you need to use:

```
int compare(const void *p, const void *q) {

   char (*p1)[1000] = (char (*)[1000])(p);
   char (*q1)[1000] = (char (*)[1000])(q);

   return strcmp(*p1, *q1);
}
```